# How to share a document for edit outside organization in #MicrosoftGraph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to perform two types of sharing operations using MicrosoftGraph:

(1) Is it possible to use #MicrosoftGraph to share an Office365 document outside my organization? In Google phrasing, I've created a document under custom app domain `ACME.COM`, and I'd like to allow some arbitrary `USER@FOO.COM` write access to the document.

(2) Is it possible to use #MicrosoftGraph to share an Office365 document to anyone with the link to the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> > (2) Is it possible to use #MicrosoftGraph to share an Office365 document to anyone with the link to the document?

Yes, we are able to share the document link using Microsoft Graph to anonymous.  However, anonymous links may be disabled by the tenant administrator, please ensure it is enable before you share the document to anonymous.

Here is an example for your reference:

POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/microsoft.graph.createLink

```
authorization: bearer {token}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "type": "view",
  "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

## Update:

Now we are able to send a sharing invitation to an existing item. A sharing invitation creates a unique sharing link and sends an email to the recipient of the invitation that includes the sharing link.

Sample:

```
POST:https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/itemId/invite

authorization: bearer {token}

Content-type: application/json

{
"recipients": [ { "email": "mailAdress" } ],
"message": "Here's the file I mentioned during our meeting.",
"requireSignIn": true,
"sendInvitation": true,
"roles": [ "write" ]
}
```

Refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_invite) about this API.